# Yet another question why django can't see the app

Tags: python, django

I want all the apps to be in the same shared **apps** folder. But django settings doesn't want to see the created app.

how I created the app

1. Created an empty apps folder in the project root directory.
2. Created an empty `__init__.py` file in it
3. Created an empty folder inside apps folder - `creative_performer`
4. Run the command `python manage.py startapp creative_performer apps/creative_performer`

Got the following structure

```
/gpanel
    /projects
        urls.py
        settings.py
        ....
     /apps
        __init__.py
            /creative_performer
                /migrations
                __init__.py
                apps.py
                models.py
                ....
```

manage.py

**settings.py**

```
PROJECT_APPS = ['creative_performer']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
] + PROJECT_APPS
```

But after server run got

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'creative_performer'
```

I have also tried creating an app with the command

```
django-admin startapp creative_performer
```

Same result

If create an app in the root of the project, without using the `apps` shared folder, everything starts working

Else tried change `PROJECT_APPS` to `PROJECT_APPS = ['apps.creative_performer']`

But got

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'creative_performer'. Check that 'apps.creative_performer.apps.CreativePerformerConfig.name' is correct.
```

But `CreativePerformerConfig.name == 'creative_performer'` , it's not clear why the error occurs

**P.S.**

Resolved by change `apps.py` changing     `name = 'apps.creative_performer'`

and **settings.py**

```
PROJECT_APPS = ['apps.creative_performer']
```

But, is this normal django behaviour ? Is it really impossible to create apps inside a shared folder without changing the default settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's `installed_apps` uses Python's normal import system to locate the installed apps. At the end of the day, this is what matters: that your apps can be located and imported, which follows the python packaging and import semantics. So, for most third-party apps you install via `pip` are already available on the PYTHONPATH to be imported as a top-level name.

Because your app `creative_performer` is actually a subpackage under `apps`, you need to use `'apps.creative_performer'` in your `installed_apps` and set the app name to the same to use it in this case.

Another option would be to remove the `apps/__init__.py` file and add the `apps` directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable (or modify `sys.path`) to deal with this. That way, your apps are just standalone packages. But the correct thing to do would probably be to leave it as you have it with `'apps.creative_performer'` -- which is similar to what django does in its `contrib` subpackages, [for example](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c614e811f80ae5ce4e8f1461f54f0600707cf0e6/django/contrib/auth/apps.py#L15). Generally, modifying your pythonpath is discouraged.

Yet another option would be to distribute your apps as [reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/reusable-apps/#your-project-and-your-reusable-app) and install them separately altogether.